# How to integrate an Admob interstitial in a Processing.org sketch in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, processing

I've been struggling with Admob integration in a Processing.org sketch converted into an Android app for some time. First I've got a banner properly working (so I know Admob is correctly setup), but now I'd like to have an interstitial too.

I've followed this tutorial to complete the integration: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/integrating-new-google-admob-banner-interstitial-ads/

However, I haven't been able to make layouts work with the app since sketch apps do not have an explicit call to setContentView() (I think the problem is related to this point). When I try to launch the app, it does not respond but there is no visible error message.

Has anybody a hint about how to make an explicit layout work with a Processing.org sketch Android app, or even better, has anybody an example project that successfully integrates Admob interstitials? Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe you can show the code where you integrated the interstitial? Also for interstitials there should not be any changes in layout necessary as they show up in fullscreen size.